# Solving Ordinary differential inequations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there methods for solving (or at least giving relations) the most classical Ordinary Differential **Inequation** as it is the case for the Ordinary differential equations?

Comment: Please give an example. I have no good idea what you mean.

Comment: For instance, $f'+a f \geq 0$. Here a(.) is continuous

Comment: There is always the Grönwall lemma/theorem. In your example, multiplication with the integrating factor will provide a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks. What about $f''+af'+bf \geq 0$, (a and b real numbers) ?
It seems that Grönwall lemma gives estimates for $f$ and only for $f'+af \geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your level and motivation about the subject but you could check out [Partial Differential Relations](https://www.ihes.fr/%7Egromov/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/248.pdf) and the [h-principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_principle) written by M.Gromov, which aim to solve differential relations of partial derivates and in a rather general way.

It requires a good understanding of Homotopy Theory, Differential Topology and Differential Geometry and written rather densely.

If we treat PDEs as an extension of ODEs maybe you could de-generalize it to Ordinary Differential Relation/Inequality problems. I am not sure the answers would be satisfactory enough for you though, in the sense of getting quasi-closed-form solutions and specific function classes.